# sql select table where a column not in a set with exception another column equal to something

Tags: sql

new to SQL. I searched around but could not find the answer. I have a table

```
 Name   Status1     Status2
    A   Canceled    same_day
    B   Cancelled   Cancelled
    C   Completed   Completed
    D   Completed   Completed
```

I want to return a table where Status1 not in the set ('Canceled','Cancelled') with exception that Status2 = 'same_day'. Basically, my desired return is

```
 Name   Status1     Status2
    A   Canceled    same_day
    C   Completed   Completed
    D   Completed   Completed
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well what have you tried?

Comment: Even if you are new to SQL, you should have tried something.  It's as easy as it gets.  It doesn't get any easier than this.  If you don't even want to try this query, how can you improve???

Comment: Sorry got confused since the original problem has some mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select *

from MyTable

where Status1 not in ('Canceled','Cancelled') 
or Status2 = 'same day'

PS: It is really strange that you couldn't find an answer. I recommend that you read this tutorial throughout:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: This is not correct, ‘same day’ should be included not excluded

Comment: Of course, you are right. Too quick to write. Simple code produces the most errors lol...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

SELECT * FROM {tablename} WHERE Status1 NOT IN ('Canceled', 'Cancelled') OR Status2 = 'same_day'